# how to connect meteor with react native app using react-native-meteor library

Tags: android, meteor, react-native

I am making a react native app. I am using react-native meteor library to connect my native app to my meteor web app.
There is problem in this library. It makes my app connect to my meteor app using these link `ws://192.168.1.66:3000/websocket` or `ws://localhost:3000/websocket`
I  tried this but it is not working. I am not getting my data through this. If anyone could tell me that what I am really missing here, am I doing something wrong?

I am using windows operating system for development.
here is an image to understand the problem.
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txJgs.png)

after i changed my code like this it works fine when i insert dummy data in my state.ledgers and update it with this code .

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 this.setState({ ledgeres: nextProps.ledgered })
}
```

it works fine first like this
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqWHW.png)

but it turns back as it was

Comment: Did you start your meteor server?

Comment: yes i did start it

Comment: How do you want to get the data? Via a subscription, query of the collection, ...?

Comment: i added an image in the question u can see it

Comment: yes i want it by subscription

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `ledgered` props should be in the state.

So you should add a function `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`

In this function you should do something like

```
this.setState({ ledgered: nextProps.ledgered })
```

So your render will be called with the ledgered in the state of the component.

Also, in your constructor, you should initialize your state with an empty array called `ledgered`

Hope it's help you!